# Operations perform differently in notebook and terminal interfaces

Tags: external-calls, raspberry-pi

The following command executed on a Raspberry Pi equipped with a RaspiCam behaves differently depending on whether the command is run from the terminal (via `wolfram`) or a notebook (via `mathematica`):

```
<<"!raspistill -t 5 -k -o image.jpg"
```

In the terminal, the function behaves as expected: a preview window appears and raspistill maintains control until the user presses Enter twice.  In the notebook interface, however, raspistill behaves *as if* it is receiving keypresses and eventually exits.  It is possible to work around this issue to execute a terminal which calls raspistill, e.g.:

```
<<"!lxterminal -e \"raspistill -t 5 -k -o image.jpg\""
```

Does anyone know why the behavior of executing external commands would differ between the two flavors (?) of Mathematica, or how I might go about debugging this issue further?

Comment: Note to self: [useful ref](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84173/7167)