# Is ClearAttributes built-in functon work in current cell only?

Tags: clear

I have a question. Is ClearAttributes the built-in functon work in current cell only? This is my code:

In first cell:

```
Set[a, 6]
```

In second cell:

```
ClearAttributes[Set, HoldFirst]
Attributes[Set]
Set[a, 7]
```

As you can see in the second cell there is no attribute HoldFirst of Set function.

However, if I make a call in the third cell:

```
Attributes[Set]
```

It turns out that the Set function has a HoldFirst attribute.

So does the ClearAttributes function only work in the cell in which it is called?

Comment: No. `ClearAttributes` happens at the kernel level. `Cells` are a front-end construct. If this doesn't make sense [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84177/38205) will help. You're omitting the fact that your `Set[a, 7]` causes a huge string of failures. Clearly `Set` resets itself, restoring its `HoldFirst` state.

Comment: You cannot reliably change the attributes or definitions of core system functions like `Set`. These functions have certain optimizations that insulate them from the full generality of the langage. This often means that any user-assigned attributes and definitions are either ignored or reset without warning.